# Get value from AJAX using Javascript and ASP

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp-classic

I am using this Ajax code. But I dont know how i will retrieve my value of value1 on my server-side asp using Javascript.

On my serverside I want to have something like 
<%
var newdata = value1 ( which is the one from the serverside - which was send here) 
%>

Please Help !!! thanks a million

I know it is possible with PHP but how do i do with javascript

```
    <script>
function ajaxNow(_data)
{
  var xmlHttp;
  try
  {
    /* Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari */
    xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  catch (e)
  {
    /* newer IE */
    try
    {
      xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (e)
    {
      /* older IE */
      try
      {
        xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      catch (e)
      {
        alert("Your browser is old and does not have AJAX support!");
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4)
    {
      /* this puts the value into an alert */
      alert("Value read is: "+xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
  }
  xmlHttp.open("GET","ajax_file.asp?value1="+_data,true);
  xmlHttp.send(null);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your Ajax-Request succeeds you will have the querystring-variables in the QueryString-Collection of the Request-Object.

Could work like this on the server side:

```
<% var newdata = Request.QueryString("value1"); %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Client-side Javascript can't query server-based databases for obvious reasons. Based on what you appear to be doing, I would suggest you code an ASP which performs the actual query using VBA / C# / whatever, and you can then parse the results in your client-side ajax call as normal.

Comment: just to expand on that, lookup jQuery and JSON. Create the asp page "my-results.asp", then use js to call that page $.ajax or $.load

Comment: jQuery also has a `$.getJSON` function which might be useful. As long as you code your ASP page to return properly formatted JSON this will be the most effective way.

Answer (score 1):

URL encode `_data` and `nbquestions` variables. `Request.QueryString("param1")` will decode them for you.

JavaScript URLEncode:

```
escape(_data);
```

Also you can use Server.URLEncode() methods from VB script.

Comment: how would i do that ? sorry but i am really new at this :( with URLencode(_data) ? would you be able to give me an example on serverside and on client side ( encode decode )ty

Comment: would I be able to do this: xmlHttp.open("Get","CmsAjax.asp?param1="+escape(_data)+"&param2="+escape(nbquestions),true) and on server-side my request.querysting ? thanks for the update

Comment: Is the call you doing in VB script or JavaScript?

Comment: xmlHttp.open("Get","CmsAjax.asp?param1="+Server.URLEncode(_data)+"&param2="+Server.URLEncode(nbquest?ions),true) tired like that and not working :(

Comment: no :( i dont know what I am doing wrong tried like 10 diffrent ways with post/get etc and nothing. I am able to make it work with get if i send only one value but when I send 2 values it doens;t work anymore

Comment: How big is the Query String that gets generated? You might be running in to [this](http://www.asp101.com/tips/index.asp?id=102). If that's the case you need to use post.

Answer (score 1):

> xmlHttp.send correctly writen

- It doesn't check that you have a `200` status before trying to deal with the data.
- It fails to [encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) the data to make sure it is URL safe

I would suggest using a library to handle XHR stuff, instead of reinventing the wheel. [Microjs](http://microjs.com/#ajax) has a list of lots of small libraries if you aren't using one of the large ones (such as [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) or [jQuery](http://jquery.com)).

> how do I get the values on the server-side using Javascript.

It is just query string data, so it will be in `Request.QueryString`.

Comment: on the serverside i would do value1 = Request.QueryString(param1);value2=Request.QueryString(param2) ? and for the encoding would i need to use : xmlHttp.send("param1="+escape(_data)+"&param2="+escape(nbquestions)); ? thanks for your help !

Comment: I don't know ASP well enough to answer the first one confidently. And no, you wouldn't use `escape`. `escape` is deprecated, you use `encodeURIComponent` (which I linked to in the answer).

Comment: oh sorry my bad:(. One more questions would i need to put all in one string like : try1 = encodeURIComponent("param1="+_data+"&param2="+nbquestions); and after do xmlHttp.send(try1); or would i be able to do xmlHttp.send("param1="encodeURIComponent(+_data)+"&param2="+encodeURIComponent(nbquestions)); THANKS sorry but i am really new at this and very lost :P

Comment: You need to encode the data, not the whole URI. Encoding the whole URI will turn `=` and `&` into data so they'll stop being separate key/value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

you can make the asp page write the result as JSON format read in directly via XMLHttpRequest Object and later processing:

example of JSON

```
var myJSONObject = {"bindings": [
        {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "newURI", "regex": "^http://.*"},
        {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "deleteURI", "regex": "^delete.*"},
        {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "randomURI", "regex": "^random.*"}
    ]
};
```

then you can use native parsers in web browsers or eval() (NOT RECOMENDED, SERIOUSLY!!!) to parse the data written in your asp page and use it in your javascript client code.

More information about [JSON](http://www.json.org/js.html) basic info

JSON in browsers:

- [Internet Explorer 8+](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/09/10/native-json-in-ie8.aspx)
- [Mozilla Firefox/Sea Monkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON)
- in Opera, Chrome, Safari works too

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the server-side script outputs will be picked up by the AJAX request. So if the AJAX requests something, the server-side does the legwork and fetches the result from the database and then outputs it.

There are loads and loads of tutorials on how to do exactly this. Just ensure that you secure your script properly so that it's not open to abuse.

Answer (score 1):

```
//(javascript, ajax = xmlHttp)
```

if your response text is an array you can use this.

```
var myArray = eval(xmlHttp.responseText);
```

or if it is a just text you can use .

```
var value = xmlHttp.responseText
```

Another approach.This is just a template. If you use jquery, you can use this approach. i hope it solve your problem or give an idea.

html part:

```
<div id="willupdate"></div>
<div id="willupdate2"></div>
```

JQuery part:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

getValue("serverurl",updateName)
getValue("serverurl",updateSurName)
 });

function updateName(name){
 $("#willupdate").text(name)
}


function updateSurName(name){
 $("#willupdate2").text(name)
}

function updateSurName(name){
 $("#willupdate").text(name)
}

function getValue(url,opt_onRecieved){
    if( !url || url == ""){
        alert("request url error");
        return;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: url,
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(data){
            opt_onRecieved(data);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: the use of eval() is a potential security hole!

Comment: One questions let's say that I have 20 functions on my server-side ASP. They will be all ran when I run my ajax function from my client-side, so how do i specify that i want only the string comming out of the specific function from my server-side. And how do I say it is that data that I want to have when i write my function in my server-side ASP. Thanks a lot for ur help

Comment: you can't specify that in client code directly you have 2 options - first that you send a parameter to the request and the asp page based on the parameter writes only the requested info , or - SECOND that you write everything and in client you made something to identify the needed data and process acordling.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very good ajax tutorial. There is everything explained. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX/Getting_Started

You forget a double quote:

```
xmlHttp.open("post","CmsAjax.asp",true)
```

To get the data:

```
/* this puts the value into an alert */
alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
```

Comment: the xmlHttp.responseText isn't it for what i am receving from the server ? Me i need to have the 2 values on the server-side and there I run a function that puts the values into the database SQL

Comment: I am not sure if we mean the same thing. But for sure is that the xmlHttp.responseText is the response of the server. But do you care about the response anyway? Or do you just want to write the values in the database and that's it?

Comment: I just want to write the values into the database: so i get the values from a flash movie-> send them to the client-side -> send them to serverside -> send them to a PL/sql and after in Oracle. for now i just need to get the data into the database

Comment: What server do you use and which  programming language?

Comment: sql. I tried it before with  get  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728505/get-values-on-server-side-sent-with-xmlhttp-openget . If i pass only one value it works fine but when i try to pass 2 values it doesnt work :( If you would be able to help me I would always owe you !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the data on the server and then decode them in the client. You can use JSON-RPC for this.

Here are few links:

[Official Website](http://json-rpc.org/)

[Wikipedia Article about JSON-RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC)

[Implementations of JSON-RPC Service in different languages](http://json-rpc.org/wiki/implementations)

But you don't need to use JSON-RPC if you have only one value you can encode as JSON in ASP and then decode it in JavaScript

```
var array = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
```

Comment: so I would use the same methode i used and after I just have to decript the .responsetext ? How would I run the function on the server to get the values. Sorry really new at this Thanks a lot for ur help =)

Comment: Here is asp library for json - http://code.google.com/p/aspjson/ and here is another one http://www.webdevbros.net/2007/04/26/generate-json-from-asp-datatypes/

Comment: Is this for ASP.net ? I have to use ASP classic aka notepad :P

Comment: I don't know if they are for ASP.Net. If there is no such function/library for classic ASP, then maybe you will need to write it yourself. It's not difficult you have only 4 data types: string, number, array and object/asoc array and 3 constants true, false and null. JSON documention: http://www.json.org/. The other options is to use xml or non standard way of encoding arrays like using data separated by e.g. `::` and then in JavaScript using `xmlHttp.responseText.split('::');`