# get values on server-side sent with xmlHttp.open(GET

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, asp-classic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get value from AJAX using Javascript and ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666404/get-value-from-ajax-using-javascript-and-asp)

How do I retrieve the values of the querystring that is being send to my serverside asp page from my client side ajax call?

This is what i am sending from client-side:

```
xmlHttp.open("Get","CmsAjax.asp?param1=" + _data + "&param2=" + nbquestions,true)
```

On my serverside, I want to get the querystring values. I tried this but I don't know why it is not working.

```
   var gAnswer = Request.QueryString("param1");
   var nbQuestions = Request.QueryString("param2");
```