# Example of getting data from database using javascript?

Tags: javascript, sql, ajax, asp-classic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get values on server-side sent with xmlHttp.open(GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728505/get-values-on-server-side-sent-with-xmlhttp-openget)
>   [Get value from AJAX using Javascript and ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666404)

Hi does anyone have an example on how to get some data out of a SQL database using ASP (classic not the .Net ) javascript - serverside and client-side. I am trying to use Ajax .reponsetext . Thanks a lot for your help. I can't seem to find any example. :(