# How to get the value of a function that is on the server-side on to the client-side (.responsetext)

Tags: javascript, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get value from AJAX using Javascript and ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666404/get-value-from-ajax-using-javascript-and-asp)

I have a webpage that needs to get some values from the server( SQL -Oracle) and I am trying to use 
.responseText to get the info from the server-side to the client-side. The info is an Array. On the serverside
I have a function that needs to get the values from the Database. I tried something but i get a long test as response

```
<!doctype HTML public"-// W3C .... etc. 
this is my code from client-side. 
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4)
    {
    alert(xmlHttp.responseText)
    var tabScore = new Array();
    tabScore= xmlHttp.responseText;
```

Please help me if you know how to =). 
I think my question is how to i get the value/result of a function that is on the server-side to the client-side
P.s using ASP and Javascript