# how to use .responsetext , getting value from server-side

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp-classic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the value of a function that is on the server-side on to the client-side (.responsetext)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756741/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-function-that-is-on-the-server-side-on-to-the-client-s)
>   [Get value from AJAX using Javascript and ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7666404)

When you are using `.responsetext` to get a value from the serverside asp (javascript ) how does the value has to be on the server-side. In other words I am creating a function that gets some data from the database. This function is on the server-side and i would like to get that answer onto my client-side in order to desplay it. 
Thanks for your help